# int list -> int instead of 'a list -> 'a

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, type-inference

i'm new to ocaml (which i'm learning at school), and in my exercice, i need to write a function which gives the minimum of the list of int. I wrote that :

```
let rec minimum liste =
    match liste with
    |[a] -> a
    |[a;b] -> if a<b then a else b
    |a::b::r -> if a<b then minimum (a::r) else minimum (b::r)
    ;;
```

However, ocaml tells me :

```
val minimum : 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
```

And as I said, I need `val minimum : int list -> int = <fun>`
Could you help me, please ? Thanks !

Comment: So the teacher asked you to make a machine to find the smallest apples but you build a machine that finds the smallest of any fruit. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything that depends on the inputs being any particular type. So OCaml (more or less correctly) infers that it will work for a list of any type.

If you like, you can limit the types of function parameters by specifying them like this:

```
 let f (x: type) = ...
```

So you can say:

```
let rec minimum (liste: int list) = ...
```

(As a side comment, you might try your function on an empty list to see what happens.)